# Adding a dictionary to a collection - just the values?

Tags: c#, collections

I am filling a combobox with dropdown values of type `WagonType`. The function I am calling returns a dictionary where the key is the `WagonTypeID` and the value is the `WagonType`.

```
RepositoryItemComboBox comboWagonTypes;
Dictionary<int, WagonType> GetAllWagonTypes()
{
  ...
}
```

If I use AddRange to fill the collection will it insert only the values or both the keys and the values?

```
comboWagonTypes.Items.AddRange(GetAllWagonTypes());
```

Or do I need to iterate through the dictionary and insert the values myself?

```
foreach (var wagonType in GetAllWagonTypes())
   comboWagonTypes.Items.Add(wagonType.Value)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the [Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekcfxy3x%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property of the dictionary.

Just do

```
comboWagonTypes.Items.AddRange(GetAllWagonTypes().Values);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s620ab8x.aspx) property. Dictionary has Keys and Values as properties. Give it a try!